# How can I pass props from one child component to another and render in parents with reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing props from one child component to another and render the data in a parents.
Below is where I am capturing data

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CSVUpload from './Components/CSVUpload';
import AreaChart from '../Dashboard2/DashboardCharts/AreaChart';
import Dashboard2 from '../Dashboard2/Dashboard';




export default function DataStorage(){
    
    const [csvData, setCSVData] = useState([]);

    const handleCSVDataLoaded = (data) => {
        setCSVData(data);
        
      };
    
    return(
        <>
    <h1>CSV Upload Example</h1>
      <CSVUpload onDataLoaded={handleCSVDataLoaded}  />

        </>
    )
}
```

Here I can upload data. This works well. Now I want to pass the data to the following child

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts';

const AreaChart = (props) => {
    const csvData = props.csvData;
    // Extract the necessary data from 'csvData' for the plot
    const categories = csvData.slice(1).map(item => item[0]);
    const data_ = csvData.slice(1).map(item => item[1]);
    console.log(categories)
    const data_series_name = 'Value'; // Provide a name for the series

  const options = {
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      categories: categories,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false, // Set to false to turn off the display of values
    },
    chart: {
      toolbar: {
        show: true, // Turn off the download option
      },
    },
  };

  const series = [
    {
      name: data_series_name,
      data: data_,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Paper elevation={4}>
      <Chart options={options} series={series} type="area" height={500} />
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default AreaChart;
```

and I want to render here

```
import React from 'react';
import AreaChart from '../Dashboard2/DashboardCharts/AreaChart';

const RenderPlot = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>PLOT</h2>
       <AreaChart />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RenderPlot;
```

How can I make it work ? it is not working the way I expecting. Meaning the AreaChart should be rendered on the desired section only

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. All three components don't reference each other except that the last one uses `AreaChart`.

Comment: I want to get the data from DataStorage, pass it to AreaChart . The AreaChart should be rendered at RenderPlot. that is what I am looking for

Comment: You need to store your CSV data in local storage or React Context, and use it inside `RenderPlot` component.

Comment: How can I do that ? I know I could store it in a database. but I need to pass the data between components

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Comment: I am not sure , if this going to solve the problem. I only need to render AreaChart in Renderplot. but the data should be passed from DataStorage. Meaning the DataSorage should not be rendered in RenderPlot

Comment: Yeah I understand. So this is not the scenario of prop drilling (and that's why I deleted my answer) but still the link is helpful in understanding Context.